# Objective-C/IOS : Delete data in coredata

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, entity, delete-row

I have 2 entities **LETTER** and **LETTER.NUMBER** example:

- A - A.1 ,A.2 ,A.3 ,A.4 ,...
- B - B.1 ,B.2 ,B.3 ,B.4 ,...
- C - C.1 ,C.2 ,...
- D - D.1 ,...

When i delete **LETTER** ,i also want to delete all the children data example:

- Delete A ----> Delete A.1 ,A.2 ,A.3 ,A.4 ,...
- Delete B ----> Delete B.1 ,B.2 ,B.3 ,B.4 ,...

In other database framework ,we can use primary key to achive that. But i don't know how to set primary key in Objective-C.
Can someone show me how to do that or suggest a tutoral that i can follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very easy task. Open xcdatamodel in xcode. Then select the entity 'LETTER'. Here you must have a reltionship with entity 'LETTER.NUMBER'. Select the relationship, then in the data model inspector of xCode (the right most item in the right panel) set the delete rule to 'Cascade'.

Now when you delete your LETTER object, all LETTER.NUMBER objects associated with it will also be deleted

Comment: Thanks a lot ! btw for some need more info
[link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dkesIrpmAug)

Answer (score 0):

You need to cascade the deletion, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH2-SW1. Use the apple's document.